# foreach a decoded Base64 string after use $_GET

Tags: php, foreach, base64

i have problem, when POST informations in URL without encode it all is fine and i can use foreach for all informations because i got it as array

but when use GET and decode it, informations convert from array to string and can't use foreach anymore, (i try encode it again as json but i fail).

i have base64 value in URL like this

```
http://www.test.com/index.php?info=dXNlcm5hbWU9PmJyb29rcwpjb2xvcj0+Ymx1ZQp1cmw9Pmh0dHA6Ly93d3cudGVzdC5jb20vNDE0Mg==
```

i use `$info = base64_decode($_GET['info']);` to get it and decode

i want foeach it inside li like this `echo <li>$info_key is $info_value</li>`

> NOTE: when decode it you will see i'm using => between key and value, and use return line for each array, maybe i can use PHP_EOL to split or collect
>
> Another NOTE: i don't know how much values will get from url so because that i need to use foreach to loop all collected values

Thank you stackoverflow community ✌

Comment: You cant foreach over a string

Comment: so any other method to echo all informations inside <li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once decoded your string looks like:

```
username=>brooks
color=>blue
url=>http://www.test.com/4142
```

`foreach` is for looping over iterables, so you would need to parse it into an array.

```
<?php
$str = base64_decode('dXNlcm5hbWU9PmJyb29rcwpjb2xvcj0+Ymx1ZQp1cmw9Pmh0dHA6Ly93d3cudGVzdC5jb20vNDE0Mg==');

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $line = explode('=>', $line);
    echo '<li>'.$line[0].' is '.$line[1].'</li>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/TodEB

```
<li>username is brooks</li>
<li>color is blue</li>
<li>url is http://www.test.com/4142</li>
```

Though you should just avoid what you're doing and pass them as parameters.

Comment: thank you verymush but i have problem, i try same code in my localhost "XAMPP" and i get like this [img](https://image.ibb.co/np8GNp/2018_08_28_004240.png) i don't know what problem !!,  my php version is 7.2.3

Comment: Update your code, the example I provided does not do that. Also you might want to add http_build_query then you know your expecting an array back not some custom format https://3v4l.org/0vk3o

Comment: i try it but can't get same your resault in answer, why it work in 3v4l.org and other online php editor but in my localhost not work, help me sir

Comment: please help me, i don't know what problem exactly

Comment: same your code, i'm copy it and paste in other live php editor and it's work fine, but in my localhost i have problem, and i find problem in base64_decode because when use direct informations without encode it like this $str = 'username=>brooks
color=>blue
url=>http://www.test.com/4142'; i not get any problem, why i have this problem only in localhost, any idea to fix it

Comment: So whats it doing locally? Can you view the source and post that somewhere? Its most likely todo with wrong newline chars (which is why I said dont do it, its one of the issue amongst the many things like someone changing a char breaks everything). Is the base64 string the same? If not post that somewhere.. Its hard to tell as im not sitting at your screen ;p

Comment: i not have any website right now to test it i only work in one project in localhost. i'm downloading MAMP to test it, maybe problem in XAMPP

Comment: problem in return line, i'm change return line to & and it's work, thank you sir

Comment: I dont understand.. there is no return in the code.

Comment: i mean i'm replace new line with "&" in base64 encode url and replace PHP_EOL in php code to "&" . thank again :D

Comment: another information : when write var_dump(PHP_EOL); in php code i get output like this string(2) " " not give me return line, so that mean localhost replace return line to space

Comment: i have question, i find another method, i'm replace PHP_EOL to "\n", it's good idea or will cause errors in future or something ?

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off doing something like JSON encoding (instead of your custom thing) and then base64 encode that?